# GWT + Tomcat Session without Cookies!

Tags: session, gwt, tomcat, cookies, session-cookies

I'm working on a web-project which uses GWT on client and Java on server side (tomcat7).

If cookies are enabled on the browser, everything works fine. I can use sessions without any problems.

If cookies are disabled on the browser, sessions doesn't work.

I guess, this his mainly something to do with GWT apps being a single web-page application which only requests data from the server via ajax.

Is there a way to get sessions working under such circumstances?

Help is very appreciated!

All the best,
Thomas

Comment: I've found that tomcat doesn't setup sessions if it's an HTML file - did you change your default page to be a jsp instead of HTML to get sessions to work?

Comment: No, I first need a session when a user logged in, so that's not a problem. Perhaps you configured your apache (if you have one) to serve static html files, so tomcat wouldn't create sessions ...

Answer (score 0):

If you using GWT RPC, you will need to modify your RPC urls to burn in the jsessionid as discussed in this [forum post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/9d5ccb0464a51f01). Though I am not sure if line `Cookies.getCookie("JSESSIONID")` as shown the forum post will work in your case. You might need to parse the [location.href](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#getHref%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you can access the session as follows:

```
public class NameImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements NameService {

public void doSomething()  throws IllegalArgumentException{
 HttpSession hs = this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
//Do whatever it is you want to do with this information.
}

}
```

Not 100% sure that if is what you are asking for, but it seems like the most reasonable answer.